# Solving systems given by $(x_{i}\cdot x_{i+1})\bmod (x_{i}+x_{i+1})=x_{i+2}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations

*This problem is inspired by the linked question about a recurrence (at the end of this post).*

Is there a way to solve for all solutions to the following system?

> $$(*)\begin{cases}
> x_{1}x_{2}&\bmod (x_{1}+x_{2})&=x_{3}\\
> x_{2}x_{3}&\bmod (x_{2}+x_{3})&=x_{4}\\
> x_{3}x_{4}&\bmod (x_{3}+x_{4})&=x_{5}\\
> &\dots&\\
> x_{n-2}x_{n-1}&\bmod (x_{n-2}+x_{n-1})&=x_{n}\\
> x_{n-1}x_{n}&\bmod (x_{n-1}+x_{n})&=x_{1}\\
> x_{n}x_{1}&\bmod (x_{n}+x_{1})&=x_{2}
> \end{cases}$$
>
> Where we want to find all such $x_1,\dots,x_n\in\mathbb N$ for some $n\ge 2$.

Or perhaps, this is too hard to be solved in general?

In that case, what can we say about this system and its solutions? Below are my observations.

---

Generally, if $(x_1=x_2=\dots=x_n=a,a\in\mathbb N)$, then we have:

$$
a^2\bmod 2a=\begin{cases}0,& 2\mid a\\a,& 2\not\mid a\end{cases}
$$

Giving the "trivial solution"  $(x_1,\dots,x_n)=(a,\dots,a),a=2k-1,k\in\mathbb N$ in this case.

So from now on assume otherwise (at least one $x_i,i=1,\dots,n$ is distinct), to obtain "non-trivial solutions" to the system.

Notice that "repeating" a solution of smaller $n$ gives a solution for larger $n$. For example, if $(a,b,c)$ is one solution to $n=3$, then $(a,b,c,a,b,c)$ is one solution to $n=6$. Let these solutions be called "repeated solutions".

From now on, we are interested in *nontrivial* solutions (are not "trivial" and are not "repeated").

If there aren't any additional *trivial* solutions to classify, then my question is,

> Are there ways to obtain families of nontrivial solutions for arbitrary fixed $n$ cases?

---

If $n=2$, then we have:

$$\begin{cases}
x_{1}x_{2}\bmod (x_{1}+x_{2})&=x_{1}\\
x_{2}x_{1}\bmod (x_{2}+x_{1})&=x_{2}
\end{cases}
\\\iff\\
x_{1}x_{2}\bmod (x_{1}+x_{2})=x_{1}=x_{2}
$$

Which clearly does not have any additional solutions, other than the "trivial solution"

---

For $n=3$, we have the system:

$$\begin{cases}
x_{1}x_{2}\bmod (x_{1}+x_{2})&=x_{3}\\
x_{2}x_{3}\bmod (x_{2}+x_{3})&=x_{1}\\
x_{3}x_{1}\bmod (x_{3}+x_{1})&=x_{2}
\end{cases}
$$

Notice that if $(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(a,b,c)$ is a solution, then all of the (up to six) permutations of $(a,b,c)$ are also solutions. Hence, here we search for "non-trivial solutions" in form of sets either as $S=\{a,b,c\}$ or $S=\{a,b\}$, where then actual solutions are given as $x_1,x_2,x_3\in S$.

By brute force I've found all solutions for $a,b,c\le 1000$ to be:

$$\{5,7,11\},\{69,99,111\},\{87,111,153\},\{125,475,575\},\{184,704,776\},\{315,525,735\},\{324,756,864\},\{335,365,475\},\{391,575,713\}$$

There are presumably infinitely many more?

> How can we solve for all solutions for this $n=3$ case of the system?

---

For $n\ge 4$, similarly as in $n=3$, I'm not sure how to solve for all solutions.

For $n\ge 4$, if $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ is a solution, then $(x_2,\dots,x_n,x_1),(x_3,\dots,x_n,x_1,x_2),$ $\dots$ $,(x_n,x_1,\dots,x_{n-1})$ are also solutions. Hence, we can search for nontrivial solutions in forms of sets $S=\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ where each $S$ represents up to $n$ solutions. (*Note that we allow duplicate elements in this set, and that it is ordered since solutions are obtained from it by shifting all of its elements one by one step.*)

For example, for $n=4$, one such $S$ is: $\{128,192,256,320\}$, representing four solutions: $(128,192,256,320),(192,256,320,128),(256,320,128,192),(320,128,192,256)$.

> Is it possible to solve for all such solution sets $S$ for given $n\ge 4$?

---

It appears that solution sets $S$ do exist for arbitrarily large $n$.

One way to obtain random solutions for random $n$, is to iterate the following recursion...

$$
\begin{equation}
  f_k(c_1,c_2)=f_k=\begin{cases}
    c_1, & k=1.\\
    c_2, & k=2.\\
f_{k-1}f_{k-2} \mod[f_{n-1}+f_{n-2}], & n>2.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
$$

(This recursion has been [discussed here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3489676/318073).)

...for random cases of $(c_1,c_2)$, until it enters a cycle (becomes periodic). The obtained cycle is a solution to the system $(*)$ (and hence is generated by corresponding solution set $S$).

For example, choosing $(c_1,c_2)=(137,147)$, the $f_k$ will enter the cycle (at $k=10$): $$f_{k\ge10}(137,147)=\{147,259,315,77,343,371,161\}=S$$ That cycle represents one $S$ that is one solution set for $n=|S|=7$.

Another example, iterating $f_k(189,962)$ gives a length-$18$ cycle (we enter the cycle at $k=48$), which then represents one solution set $S$ for $n=18$.

> Now, notice that if $x_1,x_2$ are a part of a solution $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ to the system $(*)$, then $f_k(x_1,x_2)$ would generate the remaining corresponding $x_3,x_4,\dots,x_n$ values at $k=3,4,\dots,n$, and start repeating all of them for all following $k\gt n$.